# The entity type [class] is not part of the model for the current context

Tags: c#, sql-server-2012, geography, entity-framework-6.1

I have db on local server and I am trying to get data using Entity Framework. VS has created edmx model and connection string automatically and now when I try to access data like this:

```
using (var context = new NSMASEntitiesTEST())
            {
                var mases = context.Mas;
                foreach (var mas in mases) //error on this line
                {
                    //
                }
            }
```

it gives me following error:

**The entity type Mas is not part of the model for the current context.**

But the thing is that I get this error only for tables that has one column of `geography` datatype (f.e. `Mas`). Other tables work fine.

I wonder if this problem could be caused just because of that geography datatype, beacuse I went through answers on similar questions and nothing worked for me.

In `Mas.cs`:

```
public partial class Mas
    {
        public int MasId { get; set; }
        public string MasName { get; set; }
        //...
        public Nullable<System.DateTime> MasContractSzif { get; set; }
        public System.Data.Spatial.DbGeography MasBoundary { get; set; }
    }
```

**EDIT:**

I have created 2 empty tables for testing:

**First** with 2 columns INT and NVARCHAR(50)

**Second** with 3 columns INT, NVARCHAR(50) and GEOGRAPHY

And it gives me error only when I want to access second table, so it is definitely caused by **geography** type.

Comment: Post the definition of Mas entity in your ObjectContext.

Comment: well, did you try to remove the `geography` then? What happened then? What similar questions did you go through? Could you link to them so as to avoid answers that suggests those solutions?

Comment: what version of Entity Framework is this?

Comment: Updated, it gives me error only when a table contains `geography` datatype.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok I have solved it. EF 6 generates this datatype wrong.

In older versions of EF, this datatype was in `System.Data.Spatial.DbGeography` and EF 6 still generating `geography` datatype like this. But it should be `System.Data.Entity.Spatial.DbGeography` now.

I have just rewrited this in each class (table) that contains `geography` datatype and all these tables are now working perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

try Linq:

```
List<int> myMasId = context.Mas.Select( x => x.MasId).ToList();
```

then you can iterate through the list.

If you want to have the whole Collection use:

```
 List<Mas> masData = context.Mas.AsQueryable().ToList<Mas>();
```

If this does not work either , what about Intellisense?

Does context.Mas show valid methods ? If not then there is a problem between context and model